# Logo Absolute Positioning not working on firefox and IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, z-index

I'm trying to make a website ( http://www.beautracare.com/ ) and the logo looks just fine on Chrome but not on the latest versions of IE and Firefox. It seems to be the popular float bug, but I put it on a different z-index. Why is this not working!? thanks,

Comment: What is "the popular float bug"?

Comment: looks fine to me with safari, chrome, and firefox.

Comment: So I added "top:0px" to the css and it fixed it, but now in IE, its appearing below the nav bar

Comment: @davethecoder: If you want to criticize the OP for just posting a link to a website instead of showing code, then please do so in a comment, but don’t edit out the website URL so that there is no useful info left at all.

Comment: @CBroe fair enough, was not reason why, was more first post filter / possible link building reasons

Comment: _“but now in IE, its appearing below the nav bar”_ – well that’s the `z-index:-2` to blame here. You should learn a litte more basics – right now, it looks like your process is based more on guessing than anything else. Oh, and go fix your [HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.beautracare.com/).

Comment: So how would I change this? right now the wsite-logo is positioned in a larger "id=logo" that takes the width of the screen. I need to know the screen width to reposition the wsite-logo, but if I change the z-index to something higher the nav buttons can't be pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
top: 0;
```

to #logo {}

When you position something absolute, it's mostly better to give it a left/top/bottom/right-value because otherwise the browser doesn't know what to do.